# Should we still allow Xml reading when we are using AdoJobStore

Tags: c#, xml, quartz.net

I have started to use `ADOJobStore` with Sql Server. I have been using `RAMJObStore` before so I was dealing with the `quartz-jobs.xml` file a lot. But now that I have switched, do I still need to to keep them on in my `quartz.config`? What is the exact role of these Xml settings?

```
# job initialization plugin handles our xml reading, without it defaults are used
quartz.plugin.xml.type = Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz
quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames = ~/quartz_jobs.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are specific to RAMJobStore so you can safely take them out. The first one points to the default plugin Quartz uses to add jobs and schedule them with triggers and can also scan the file for changes. The second one is the relative path to XML file where your jobs/triggers are located